# How to be sure entered query is a SELECT and not a DDL or DML in JDBC

Tags: sql, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, crud-repository

I have an admin panel where users can run queries. I need to be sure that only SELECT queries can run there. I am using JdbcTemplate's queryForList method `jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql)`

Can I be sure that it will only run select and not any DDL or DML command?

I tried running an update query and it returned

> Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce
> result sets.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
> Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce
> result sets.

It actually give exception just as I wanted but the description did not satisfy me. Is it possible to run a query that produce result set but also add/delete row?

Comment: Just throught of a potential problem. If the query calls a stored function or procedure, the function/procedure can perform DDL or DML queries.

Comment: (1) Have you locked down the database user (account) used to execute these queries? Make sure that DB user only has permission granted to run `select` statements (and only on the relevant tables and views). (2) "_an admin panel where users can run queries_" - depending on what exactly that means, the DB could be open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Use a locked down user which **only** has select permissions, and no permissions to modify anything or call procedures/functions/whatever which can perform modifications.

Comment: This page is in admin panel and it can insert/update in some other pages so I need that permission granted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee this. Possibly problematic cases:

- If multiple queries are allowed (`allowMultiQueries=true` for MySQL), a user might execute something which performs an update **and** selects something.
- As a variant of this, some DBMSes allow you execute blocks of procedural code which could perform updates and return rows.
- Some DBMSes (e.g. Firebird, PostgreSQL) have a `RETURNING` clause, which makes a modifying DML statement behave as a result set producing statement, while some other DBMSes support a variant of the SQL standard *data change delta table*, which allows you to use a modifying DML statement as a table in a select statement (e.g. `select * from new table (insert into example (x, y) values (1, 2))`)
- A user might call a table-valued procedure or function or use a function in a select which performs data modification
- ... possibly other scenarios ...

I'm not that familiar with MySQL, so I can't say 100% certain if (all of) my scenarios are correct for MySQL, but this pattern is common enough that I suspect some or all of them apply.

In other words, things that produce a result set are not necessarily only reading data.

In addition, some JDBC drivers will actually **execute** the statement, and then find out it didn't produce a result set and then produce an exception. Depending on whether auto-commit was enabled or not, and how auto-commit is implemented (server-side or driver-side), your statement may already have been executed and maybe even committed!

If you want to prevent a user from modifying your database you need to use one of the following:

- Use a locked down user account which only has select permission to (relevant) tables, and no permissions to any procedures, functions, etc which can modify data or perform DDL
- Use a replication solution, and connect to a read-only replica of the source database

Comment: I use this connection for an admin panel and some pages in admin panel needs DML permissions.

Comment: @ameryt Then use separate users, one with restricted permissions for the adhoc query page, and another one for the functionality that does require broader permissions.

Comment: okay I forgot we had a replica copy, just as you said, I will connect there to be sure, thank you.